# Do we want a feed of bountied (featured) questions in Mos Eisley?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, chat, chat-feed

One of the reasons to place a bounty on a question is to attract attention to it. Either to get a better answer, or to get any answer *at all*.

So how can we draw more attention? By advertising it in our main chatroom. That is why I propose to **add a "featured questions" feed** to the feeds in Mos Eisley.

Comment: Seems redundant to me tbh. Most visitors of the chatroom are the established regular users of this SE who I am sure take a look at featured tab everyday. It's not like there are a lot of featured questions (6 as of now) in any case, so there's no chance that some featured question may be left buried beneath a huge list. Reserving my vote on this however

Comment: I am indifferent about this.

Comment: gideon will tell you if you ask: `%%bounties` (up to 5, so he doesn't get rate-limited)

Comment: @KutuluMike yes, but a) you have to ask b) why have Gideon do it when there's a good feed available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Go ahead**

It can't hurt and it only adds a few extra notifications per week.

Comment: Given the support for this answer, I've gone ahead and created the feed.

Comment: @amaranth I dunno why. It worked *once* and never again before or since.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I remain firmly of the opinion that a curated feed (e.g. someone setting up a sockpuppet to post any relevant questions directly) would be just as good a solution.